# Слетел перевод длительности нахождения на сайте

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

В [профиле участника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=profile) кол-во лет и месяцев (возможно и дней тоже) указывается на английском:

> [image: англо-дни]

Хотя раньше было на русском. В транзифексе при этом [всё в порядке](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267425?key=e39b362eccc2425b04d9ef53ad0a9c27). То есть имеет место быть баг, описанный на MSE: [Translations are not used from Transifex for localized sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306244/339911)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, проблема самоустранилась. Сейчас отображается снова корректно:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]